# WSO2 Identity Server(IS) not Displaying Claims in the Default Profile

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I'm using WSO2 IS 5.3.0 in a clustered environment.
It was noticed that the claims are not being displayed in the default user profile in any of the users even after they are given as "Supported by Default". I even restarted the nodes one by one assuming it was a caching issue but that did not solve the issue either.
What could be the possible reason for this behaviour?
Could this be a configuration error?
Where should I be looking specifically(which configurations) in order to narrow down the issue?

Any valuable solution/suggestion is highly appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could you please check whether there are any errors printed in the backend terminals when you are viewing the user's profile? If so please attach them to this question.

Comment: @ShanChathusandaJayathilaka I checked the backend logs while viewing a user profile and in one of the terminals multiple lines of the following warning are evident,                                    TID: [-1234] [] [2020-11-26 21:44:10,831]  WARN {org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool} -  maxIdle is larger than maxActive, setting maxIdle to: 40

Comment: What do you mean not displayed in the default user profile? Do you mean in the management console or in some other place?

Comment: In the management console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research found out that the exact issue was simply a missing tag in the user-mgt.xml file inside <WSO2_IS_HOME>/repository/conf

```
<Property name=”initializeNewClaimManager”>true</Property>
```

After adding the missing configuration as mentioned below, the default profile displayed the claims as expected.

```
<Configuration>
 <AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>
 <AdminRole>admin</AdminRole>
 <AdminUser>
 <UserName>admin</UserName>
 <Password>admin</Password>
 </AdminUser>
 <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
 <Property name=”isCascadeDeleteEnabled”>true</Property>
 <Property name=”initializeNewClaimManager”>true</Property>
 <Property name=”dataSource”>jdbc/WSO2UM_DB</Property>
</Configuration>
```